# need help designing interactive assignment (bouncing ball game)

Tags: java

I am currently trying to figure out how to get this to work but the second line is having a problem:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
ArrayList <myCircleArray> = new ArrayList();
```

Later on I will be adding in the code to make them collide and when they hit the mouse cursor the game will end and you must click restart to do it over again, but i am currently worrying on getting this going and connect it to an index.html file in the same folder.

```
 ArrayList <myCircleArray> = new ArrayList();
    void setup(400, 400) {
  size();
  smooth();



 for(int i=0; i<myCircleArray.size(); i++) {
    myCircleArray.add ( new MovingCircle(10,10+i*10,10) ); 
}
}

void draw() {

  background(0);


for (int i=0; i<myCircleArray.size(); i++) {

  MovingCircle myCircle = myCircleArray.get(i);
  myCircle.update();
  myCircle.drawCircle();


}

  }

void mousePressed() {
myCircleArray.add ( new MovingCircle(mouseX,mouseY,10) ); 
}


class MovingCircle {

  float x;
  float y;
  float xSpeed;
  float ySpeed;

  float circleSize;

  MovingCircle(float xpos, float ypos, float csize) {
    x = xpos;
    y = ypos;


    circleSize = csize;

  }

  void update() {
    x += xSpeed;
    y += ySpeed; 
  }


  void drawCircle() {

    fill(255);
    ellipse(x, y, circleSize, circleSize);

  }


}
```

Comment: Looks like a JavaScript error in code that is not JavaScript. Where exactly is this code?

Comment: This is Java code. The C++, JavaScript, HTML, CSS tags are all erroneous. Your issue is in this line: `ArrayList <myCircleArray> = new ArrayList();`. You seem to have put the name of your variable (myCircleArray) as the Array type between the `<` and `>`. Change it to `ArrayList myCircleArray = new ArrayList();`, to remove the compiler error, but there will still be a rawtypes compiler warning until you correctly parameterize it.

Answer (score 1):

You syntax for array list is incorrect.

```
ArrayList<E> myCircleArray = new ArrayList<E>();
```

What this says:

```
Class<type> nameOfArrayListObject = new from Class<type>();
```

You use generics to create an arraylist that will hold circle objects.  Please see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) resource from the Java tutorials on generics.

But basically, A generic type is a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types. A type variable can be any non-primitive type you specify: any class type, any interface type, any array type, or even another type variable.

This is what @Tgsmith61591 means when he says "but there will still be a rawtypes compiler warning until you correctly parameterize it"

Comment: Specifically, since this is going to be a list that holds `MovingCircle` objects, it would be `List<MovingCircle> myCircleArray = new ArrayList<>();` — Note the choice of ArrayList as the type of List is an implementation detail... the variable itself can (and almost always should) be declared using the List _interface_, not a specific class implementation of the interface.  Also use the "diamond operator" on the right-hand-side to avoid unnecessarily repeating the `<E>` type.